# Match class template with default template parameters as a template argument with fewer parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I have a bunch of templates that look something like this:

```
template <class Graph>
class LinearSolver_A { /* ... */ };

template <class Graph, class Optional1 = int, class Optional2 = double>
class LinearSolver_B { /* ... */ };
```

Now, I have another template, which expects these solvers as an argument:

```
template <template <class> class LinSolver>
class SolverRunner { /* ... */ };

struct solver_not_compiled_t {}; // just a simple structure

template <>
class SolverRunner<solver_not_compiled_t> { /* ... */ };
// there is also a specialization of SolverRunner, in case it matters
```

My problem is that only linear solvers with a single template parameter (such as `LinearSolver_A`) can be matched as an argument to `SolverRunner`. But if there are any optional parameters (as in `LinearSolver_B`), they cannot be matched, even despite the defaults are supplied.

I believe `typename` cannot be used, as the templates are not complete types. How can this be solved? I would accept a solution with a wrapper, but the wrapper itself would need to be a template, and we arrive back to the same problem. I suppose this can be solved by writing a different kind of wrapper for each `LinearSolver_?`, but that is either a lot of copy-pasting or some preprocessor magic - is there really no way of doing this in a clean C++ manner?

This is kind of similar to [Why the template with default template arguments can't be used as template with less template argument in Template Template Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626759/why-the-template-with-default-template-arguments-cant-be-used-as-template-with) except there the author is not asking for a solution - I would really like to use those templates.

Sadly, no C++11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using C++11 then you can use [template aliases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Alias_templates):

```
template <class Graph>
using LinearSolver_B_Defaults = LinearSolver_B<Graph>;

template <>
class SolverRunner<LinearSolver_B_Defaults> { /* ... */ };
```

EDIT: As you can't use this feature, you could do something like this:

```
template <class Graph, class Optional1 = int, class Optional2 = double>
class LinearSolver_B { /* ... */ };

template <class Graph>
struct LinearSolver_B_Applier
{
    typedef LinearSolver_B<Graph> type;
};

template <>
class SolverRunner<LinearSolver_B_Applier>
{
    // Use typename LinearSolver_B_Applier<T>::type inside here.
};
```

Comment: Wow, how elegant! Unfortunately the project is still in the old C++. Might start writing down a list of reasons to switch to C++11 ...