# Traits class as a template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming, traits

I have traits classes sprinkled about my code which follow the same basic idiom:

```
template<class Frame, typename = void>
struct frame_traits
{
    typedef void base_frame_type;
};

template<class Frame>
struct frame_traits<Frame, typename std::void_t<
    typename Frame::base_frame_type>::type>
{
    typedef typename Frame::base_frame_type         base_frame_type;
};
```

and I have a bunch of trait checkers which use them, which also follow a similar idiom:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_base_frame_type : std::integral_constant<bool,
    !std::is_same<typename frame_traits<T>::base_frame_type, void>::value>::type {};
```

however, it turns out that `has_base_frame_type` has become useful to multiple concepts in my code, and I'd like to generalize it further so that I can pass the traits class as an additional parameter:

```
template <typename T, template<typename> class Traits = frame_traits>
struct has_base_frame_type : std::integral_constant<bool,
    !std::is_same<typename Traits<T>::base_frame_type, void>::value>::type {};
```

This doesn't work though, since [templates with default arguments cannot be used as template template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626759/why-the-template-with-default-template-arguments-cant-be-used-as-template-with).

I know I could work around the problem if I always use a traits class in the template instantiation (and modify the trait checker to accept it), namely

```
has_base_frame_type<frame_traits<MyClass>>::value
```

but I don't want to do that, because it would be [all too easy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8PyTo6NyXA) to forget and pass in a non-trait class. In fact, that's how I originally had the code written until I forgot the trait one too many times and refactored it.

Is there someway I can modify my trait class idiom to work around the template template parameter problem?

Comment: Something like the [detection idiom](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/779edd372df54f26) ?

Comment: @Piotr I'm not great at reading template metacode, but I'm not sure your traits aliases have the same properties as my traits class, namely, the typedef will always be defined no matter what the template input, but will be void if the typedef wasn't defined by `T`. Additionally, it's not obvious to me that it scales to traits classes which define multiple typedefs.

Comment: You mean [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0108aa409e8e95fe)? What dou you mean by "it doesn't scale" ? Why would you need a dummy `void` typedef, if it's just a trait?

Comment: I want things like `has_base_frame_type<double>::value` to compile (and have the value `false`).

Comment: it does compile and evaluate to false

Comment: sorry, I was trying to answer your question, not critique the code.

Comment: @Piotr it took me a minute to wrap my head around the implementation. It solves my problem, so feel free to repost as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Framework:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename AlwaysVoid, template <typename...> class Operation, typename... Args>
struct detect_impl : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> class Operation, typename... Args>
struct detect_impl<void_t<Operation<Args...>>, Operation, Args...> : std::true_type {};

template <template <typename...> class Operation, typename... Args>
using detect = detect_impl<void, Operation, Args...>;
```

Detectors:

```
template <class Frame>
using frame_traits = typename Frame::base_frame_type;

template <class Frame>
using other_frame_traits = typename Frame::other_frame_type;
```

Trait with a default detector:

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> class Traits = frame_traits>
using has_frame_type = detect<Traits, T>;
```

Test:

```
struct A
{
    using base_frame_type = void;
};

struct B
{
    using other_frame_type = void;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(has_frame_type<A>{}, "!");  // default
    static_assert(!has_frame_type<B>{}, "!"); // default

    static_assert(!has_frame_type<A, other_frame_traits>{}, "!"); // non-default
    static_assert(has_frame_type<B, other_frame_traits>{}, "!");  // non-default
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/779edd372df54f26)